# Formatting Null Dates When Importing Data To Excel From XML

Tags: xml, excel, asp-classic

I have a Classic ASP pages which is producing Excel files via XML.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=File.xls"
```

XML File header

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <DownloadComponents/>
    <LocationOfComponents HRef="file:///\\"/>
</OfficeDocumentSettings>
<ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
    <WindowHeight>12525</WindowHeight>
    <WindowWidth>15195</WindowWidth>
    <WindowTopX>480</WindowTopX>
    <WindowTopY>120</WindowTopY>
    <ActiveSheet>0</ActiveSheet>
    <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
    <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
</ExcelWorkbook>
<Styles>
    <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
        <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
        <Borders/>
        <Font/>
        <Interior/>
        <NumberFormat/>
        <Protection/>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s62">
        <NumberFormat ss:Format="dd/mm/yyyy;@"/>
    </Style>
</Styles>
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">

<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="9" ss:ExpandedRowCount="<%=objRS.RecordCount + 1%>" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
<Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Date</Data></Cell>
</Row>
```

Then for each row (just showing an example of the date column)

```
<Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="DateTime"><% if objrs("DateCol")  <> #01/01/1902# then Response.write fncFormatDateXML(objrs("DateCol")) else response.write "" end if %></Data></Cell>
</Row>
```

The fncFormatDateXML formats a date as yyyy-mm-dd:T00:00:00.000, or will output an empty string if not a valid date.

The problem I have is that, if a date cell is empty, it displays 00/01/190, but I want to to be an empty cell.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: Solution was to check for a null date.  If null, then output <Cell></Cell> and exclude the <data></data> tag.

Comment: when I just leave <Cell></Cell>, excel still generates 1900.01.01 date by default

Comment: In my XML Styles, I have this style.     <Style ss:ID="DateY4">
    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Top"/>
    <Borders>
     <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
     <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
     <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
     <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
    </Borders>
    <NumberFormat ss:Format="dd/mm/yyyy;@"/>
   </Style>.

Comment: And then when I output the null date, the cell will be: <Cell ss:StyleID="DateY4" ></Cell>.    Then my cell shows as empty.  Sorry - I don't know how to format replies in here :)

Comment: unfortunately, this did not help. Probably, this is because I'm using XML publisher, not ASP

Comment: This also worked in Oracle Reports